# Default Volume Slider in Quicktime Movie Recording

Tags: applescript, video, automation, quicktime, movie

Is there any way to change the default volume for a Quicktime movie recording?
If always defaults to 0 (muted) when starting a new movie recording.
I understand that this is done in order to prevent audio feedback, however, this is not a problem for my situation.
I have tried created an apple script in order to accomplish this through automation, but it does not work.
Any other way to adjust the volume in quicktime without having to use the mouse?

Comment: IS there really no solution?